# How to debug a while loop in Java?

Tags: java

```
public static void main (String [] args){
    double x = 100;

    while (x < 500 && x % 17 == 0 && x % 9 == 0 ){
        System.out.println(x);
        x++;
    }
}
```

I am trying to check if the number X (100 - 500 ) is divisible by 9 and 17 using the While-loop, but when I run this program the compiler shows me no results.

Can someone tell me where the problem is?

Comment: `x` is always `100` to start with. The number `100` doesn't meet all of the conditions of the while loop. Your while loop will never be entered and `x` will never increase. Everything in that while loop is effectively "dead code".

Comment: Please choose a better title.

Comment: Also be careful with doubles. I'm not sure how nicely they play with the modulo operator. `int` is probably more appropriate.

Comment: Pro tips: other than the `while loop`, your title doesn't tell us much, but it does give us slang like "Noobie" and "Plz", which is more appropriate for Facebook. If "please" is too much effort to type, Stack Overflow may not be suited to you.

Comment: @EJoshuaS: you added a couple of braces into the OP's code. Could that have been the actual problem at hand?

Answer (score 3):

The problem as commented is that you never enter your loop.
Try

```
    for (double x = 100; x < 501; x++)
    {
        if (x % 17 == 0 && x % 9 == 0)
        {
            System.out.println(x);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Should it be `x < 500`? I'm not sure if they want to include the number 500 or not.

Comment: It seems like this should just be of type "int" given that x can't possibly be anything but an integer.

Comment: I kept 100-500 only because it is what he asked for.   I kept double thinking he might actually use numbers higher than his example, but it is correct that int16 would work.

Answer (score 2):

the while will loop WHILE the given condition is true. you are going through exactly 0 iterations :P.

you should get an if inside the while. like this

```
    while (x < 500 ){
         if(x % 17 == 0 && x % 9 == 0){
             System.out.println(x);
         }
         x++ ;
    }
```

Comment: No, not a single iteration is executed.

Answer (score 1):

Others have already proposed solutions to the problem, so I won't cover that part and instead propose a different approach:

`gdc(17, 9) = 1` thus any number that is divisible by both 17 and 9 must be a multiple of `17 * 9 = 153`. This makes the whole calculation a lot simpler:

```
for(int v = 153; v < 500; v += 153)
    System.out.println(v);
```

As for using `double` in your program: `int` is totally sufficient here and avoids a lot of arithmetic pitfalls that come with `double`.

Comment: Looks like you beat me to this - I was thinking the same thing :). Incidentally, did you mean to say that 17 and 9 are relatively prime and that the least common multiple is 153? Also, shouldn't the last part of the loop be "v++" rather than "v += 153"?

Comment: @EJoshuaS no. It should be `v += 153`. The for-loop loops over all multiples of 153 below a certain threshold (500), so you have to add up 153 every time. You could as well us `for(int i = 1; i * 153 < 500; i++) System.out.println(i * 153);`. Output would be the same, as long as you only produce multiples of 153. `gcd(17, 9) = 1` is basically another way of saying they're coprime, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Your main problem is the while loop condition:

```
while (x < 500 && x % 17 == 0 && x % 9 == 0)
```

As other people have indicated, 100 is not divisible by either 17 or 9, so the loop will never run. You want to test `x % 17 == 0 && x % 9 == 0` *inside* the loop.

Joe C's example with a for loop is probably the best way to do this.

If you're into microoptimizations, you don't *actually* have to check *every* number between 100 and 500. For example, 9 and 17 are relatively prime; their least common multiple is 153. (In fact, the *only* multiples of them between 100 and 500 are 153, 306, and 459).

If you know the least common multiple of your numbers, just start checking there (i.e. start at 153 instead of 100). That works in the general case too actually.

As another point: there's absolutely no reason for `x` to be a double since it can't possibly have anything but an integer value.

Answer (score 0):

Your while loop does not execute at all. During the first iteration itself, the condition of the while loop is false, and the flow comes out of the while loop. The code mentioned by Ralph Thomas Hopper will work.

```
double x = 100;

    while (x < 500 ){
        if(x % 17 == 0 && x % 9 == 0) {
            System.out.println(x);
        }
        x++;
    }
```

Pointing out the Java documentation - see [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html). It would be useful since you are a newbie.

It says:

> The while statement continually executes a block of statements while a particular condition is true

By the way, also give a try to for loop - from 100 to 500 (as double).

Answer (score 0):

You don't gain anything from using [`double`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html) for this problem use [`int`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html) instead.

Also for one line if statements you may consider leaving out the braces as they are not technically required.

```
public static void main (String [] args) {
  int x = 100;

  while (x < 500) {
    if(x % 17 == 0 && x % 9 == 0)
      System.out.println(x);
    x++;
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that you can't put the divisibility check within the loop condition, since it will fail as soon as one number does not pass the condition, and 100 doesn't pass.

You need one loop over the numbers and a nested if statement to check divisibility.